# Socket.io implementation for chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hi i am developing application that has a chat feature.
In this app there are students and teachers. Teachers only can see their student and chat with them. Vice verse.I implemented socket.io's example about [private messaging](https://socket.io/get-started/private-messaging-part-1/) but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: you implemented it, but couldn't figure it out? Perhaps you could show us what you *implemented*?

Comment: Just implemented private message example above. Nothing else.

Comment: OK, so *implemented* means you've done it, *realized, instantiated, or brought into action* - congratulations - what's the issue?

Comment: The example above allows you to message all online people on the server. But I want the student to message only with the teacher he belongs to and the teacher with his own students.

Comment: Oh, then perhaps you want to look into `rooms` - at a guess a "room" would be tied to a teacher, and students can only "enter" a "room" if the student has that teacher - how you do that is up to you - you'd need some sort of data structure that defines all the teachers and students and which teacher(s) each student has - furthermore, if it's only student-teacher communication, you'd need to enforce that

Comment: Thanks for answering. Heard about rooms and searched it. But i have confusion. Should i create room for all teachers and let the students join? Or  need i create room for students?

Comment: that's up to you